# access to a table tr with index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get a row content in my table:

```
<div class="myTable">
   <table id="dataTable">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>First</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>second</td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
```

To get the td I use:

```
$('#dataTable').find('tbody').find('tr:nth-child(1)');
```

which works and gets the tr data, but when doing it with variable:

```
var j= 1;
 $('#dataTable').find('tbody').find('tr:nth-child(j)');
```

it fails.

What is the problem?

Comment: because you put j as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var j= 1;
 $('#dataTable').find('tbody').find('tr:nth-child(' + j +')');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use simple string concatenation and although you can reduce it to a single selector.

```
var j= 1;

$('#dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(' + j + ')');
//                           ----^^^^^^^^^----
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.eq()` function. Indexing starts with 0, so `var j = 1` will give you the second tr

```
var j= 1;
$('#dataTable tbody').find('tr').eq(j);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using either the eq() function:

```
rows.eq(0).addClass('my_class');
```

Or the :eq() selector:

```
$('tr:eq(0)', tbl).addClass('my_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres no need for `find`:-

```
var j= 1;
$('#dataTable tbody tr:nth-child(' + j +')');
```